# How to convert custom plugins to custom modules

Tags: plugin-development, modules

I have 3 custom plugins that we had someone develop for us a while ago and I would like to convert them to custom modules.  Since plugins are based upon modules, I was hoping there might be a cookbook out there.  I don't think the plugins were built using standard plugin scaffolding.

Thank you!

Comment: If the plugins are already working, just curious to the reason you'd prefer them as modules instead? Are you not using the additional plugin functionality?

Comment: No, we're not using the additional functionality.  One of the main reasons is that we don't want it to be Composer-centric, features are just part of our codebase. We are also migrating a proprietary php framework that was incomplete and hard to support to Craft/Yii. I know that I can live in blended environment with plugins/modules/proprietary code, I've been doing it for a 18mo.  But, I would prefer not.  Thank you for the response!

Comment: I've done that a few times and [this page](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/extend/module-guide.html#preparation) explains pretty much everything I needed ~ in the core they're the same.